# Does solid fat float in liquid fat?

Tags: molecular-structure, fats

Ice floats in its liquid state, water, because it is less dense, and I know fat also floats in water BUT will a piece of fat dropped into a pot of melted fat also float? or will it sink and what is it about its molecular structure that allows this?

I've searched google for about three hours and all I can find are articles on fat floating in water, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Most likely no. Typically solid is more dense than the corresponding liquid. Water is very unusual in this respect.

Comment: Water is not as unusual as you might think. There are at least four elements that behave similarly, and an untold number of alloys, polymers, ... that do as well.

Comment: Well, I never said it is unique.

Comment: @IvanNeretin - that is true.  There is a pretty strong meme (seems to start pretty early in school) that water is unique. However, I would not go even so far as to say 'very unusual' - it is just the most commonly encountered example.

Comment: so the fat would sink?
what about when gravey or or juices from cooking meat cool down and there is a layer of fat at the top? or is that just something completely different?

Comment: @JonCuster While I generally agree, which _polymer_ are you thinking about? I don't think I know one. ;-)

Comment: @cev When cooking you get a mixture of fat and water. The layer of fat on top is on top of what is mostly water.

Answer (score 11):

I thought this question was a good idea for a home experiment to do with my 8th grade son.

Into a block of dry ice, we carved a conical mold hole with the pointed end of scissors and poured canola oil into the hole:

[image]

We covered this with a second block of dry ice for about a minute and extracted the frozen oil with forceps:

[image]

Then we dropped the frozen oil into a jar of liquid canola oil:

[image]

And it sank.

Comment: Nice experiment!!

Comment: My chemistry teacher in year ten just made oil cubes (think ice cubes) from sunflower oil and showed us the same thing. But yes, nice experiment ^^